# How to use a variable in a Virtual-Key statement in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, virtual-keyboard

I'm trying to use a variable in a Virtual-Key statement in VB.Net, but I keep getting errors.  What is the correct syntax?  Without the variable, the code looks like this:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Public Shared Sub keybd_event(bVk As Byte, bScan As Byte, dwFlags As UInteger, dwExtraInfo As UInteger)
End Sub

Const VK_1 As Integer = &H31

keybd_event(VK_1, 0, 0, 0) 
keybd_event(VK_1, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

I'm trying to do:

```
keybd_event(digit, 0, 0, 0)
keybd_event(digit, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

where "digit" is the variable.  I've tried:

```
Dim digit as Byte = "VK_" & 1

Dim digit as Integer = "VK_" & 1

Dim digit as String = "VK_" & 1
```

But I get the error: "Conversion from string "VK_1" to type 'Byte' is not valid." and "Conversion from string "VK_1" to type 'Integer' is not valid."

I've tried:

```
keybd_event(VK_digit, 0, 0, 0)
```

But got the error "VK_digit is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

I also tried converting the sting to bytes and using Integer.Parse on the string but that caused errors too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable names cannot be concatenated. What you're currently trying to do with the `digit` variable is impossible, I'm afraid. You get the errors because in your attempts you are just taking a normal string and trying to convert that into a number (which doesn't work, since for example `"VK_1"` contains letters and other non-numeric characters).

However if you want to dynamically specify a number key, there are a few ways.

**For starters:** All the `VK_` key codes can be found in the [**`System.Windows.Forms.Keys` enumeration**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx), so you don't have to lookup every key you want to use.

**Secondly:** The numbers' key codes follows each other. Number `0` has the key code `48`, `1` has the key code `49`, `2` has `50`, and so on...

Thanks to the second thing I mentioned we can make it easy for ourselves by just taking the key code for `0`, and to that add the number that we want.

The simple solution:

```
Dim digit As Integer = 3 'Cannot go below 0 nor above 9.

keybd_event(Keys.D0 + digit, 0, 0, 0)
keybd_event(Keys.D0 + digit, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

---

The second, more complicated, solution is to parse a string into an enum value:

```
Dim digit As Integer = 3
Dim Key As Keys = [Enum].Parse(GetType(Keys), "D" & digit, True)

keybd_event(Key, 0, 0, 0)
keybd_event(Key, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

The good thing with the second solution is that it works for more than just numbers:

```
Dim Letter As String = "F"
Dim Key As Keys = [Enum].Parse(GetType(Keys), Letter, True)

keybd_event(Key, 0, 0, 0) 'Presses "F".
keybd_event(Key, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  Both of your solutions work nicely for me.  I would have never figured that out.

Comment: @user3080392 : I'm glad to help! The second method parses strings into the key enumeration, meaning you can use it as long as you write a correct name for one of the keys. For example `"ControlKey"` would be parsed to `Keys.ControlKey` - and since it doesn't matter if you use upper- or lowercase letters _(specified by the parameter currently set to `True`)_ you can use any kind of casing. For example `"conTRolKEy"` would also work.